# On the WordPress Admin section how do I link to submenu pages created for a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, links, tags

So i'm trying to create a WordPress plugin and I've created some menu pages using this provided function:

```
add_submenu_page('my_plugin_menu', 'Edit record page', 'Edit record page', 'manage_options', 'edit_record_page', array(&$this, 'display_edit_record_page');
```

and when I go to the page I notice on the address bar on the browser it reads something like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/wp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=edit_record_page
```

What I want to do is to be able to link this page but I find I have to hardcode the link for lack of a better way of doing it and I'm working on a dev site. So I was wondering how I could dynamically generate the link I saw on my browser so that when I copy this plugin code onto the production server it will work. Namely, is there a WordPress function that will generate the link portion of the submenu page create.

```
page=edit_record_page
```

Also, if I want to append query strings to the to the link is it as simple as adding it manually like so:

```
http://mydomain.com/wp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=edit_record_page&rec_id=1
```

or is there an appropriate WordPress function for doing that too?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`admin_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) gets you the correct administration page URL (and [`network_admin_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/network_admin_url) to get a network administration page URL)

Optionally, you can use [`add_query_arg()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) to append arguments to an URL, using an associative array:

```
$page       = 'edit_record_page';
$rec_id     = 1;
$record_url = add_query_arg(compact('page', 'rec_id'), admin_url('admin.php'));
```

Answer (score 3):

`<a href="admin.php?page=edit_record_page">Link Text</a>`

and

`<a href="admin.php?page=edit_record_page&rec_id=1">Link Text</a>`

Comment: This works, however can you show an example of using admin_url(); inline like this?